# in kinetic js fill element(shape) with image

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am making different shapes inside canvas using Kinetic js. I inserted image into shape but not able to resize image inside shape.
User will give input x,y,height and width of image. Then image of given size will be inserted into shape.

I can not insert images here because of less reputation.
You will understand my question easily by viewing [js fiidle](http://jsfiddle.net/2snca9x8/)

Here is my code sample

```
$(img).load(function() {
    blueCircle.fillPatternImage(img);
    blueCircle.fillPatternOffset({x:100, y:105});
    layer.draw();
});
img.src = "";
img.src = "http://www.fusemobile.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/mobile-social-network-300x225.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fillPatternScale(scale)` to scale the image, for example:

```
$(img).load(function() {
    blueCircle.fillPatternImage(img);
    blueCircle.fillPatternOffset({x:150, y:105});
    blueCircle.fillPatternScale({ x: 0.4, y: 0.4 });
    layer.draw();
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2snca9x8/1/)

Comment: yes, it works, but tell me what is 0.4 in scale? And one more question, can we blur edges of shape??

Comment: `x` and `y` can take values between 0 and 1, 1 being 100% of the original dimension. So, `x: 0.4` means 40% of the original width. Not sure I can help you with blurring the edges